# Pyinotify -- event raised from original path after directory renaming

Tags: python, linux, inotify, pyinotify

I use pyinotify to monitor my file system. The problem is when I rename a directory and create file in the renamed directory, the event is raised from original path(referred by `event.name`). Can't figure out what is wrong? Any problem with the `add_watch` flag when initializing the watcher? Currently the flag is set as `rec=True, auto_add=True`.

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `IN_MOVE_SELF` event to your mask.

[Source](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/issues/32)

Comment: This almost worked, but my need was slightly different. I used IN_MOVED_TO. And I also had to add a new handler `def process_IN_MOVED_TO(self, event):`